# bash remove duplicate lines from txt files in folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, uniq

I have this command to remove duplicate lines from a file and save the unique lines in a new file

```
uniq telphone.txt output.txt
```

However Im trying to find a command that scans all `.txt` files in the current folder and removes duplicates and saves it as the same filename

That will find `telphone.txt` remove duplicates and save it as `telphone.txt`.

Then if a new file `homes.txt` exists, to do the same and save it as `homes.txt`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

for file in ./*.txt; do
    cp "$file" "$tmpfile" &&
    uniq "$tmpfile" >$file"
done

rm "$tmpfile"
```

This loops over all the names that end in `.txt` in the current directory and removes duplicated lines from each of them in turn.

The file is first copied to a temporary file, and this temporary file is then processed with `uniq`.  The output is written to the original filename.

Doing it this way ensures that the permissions on the original files are not altered (which they may be if one did `uniq "$file" >"$tmpfile"` followed by `cp "$tmpfile" "$file"`).

The call to `uniq` is also depending on the `cp` to be successful.  If the `cp` failed, the `uniq` command's redirection would otherwise truncate the original file and you would loose that data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a temp file, as `uniq` or `>` will truncate the file when opening.

Try this,

```
for f in *.txt; do
    tmpf=$(mktemp)
    uniq "$f" "$tmpf" && mv "$tmpf" "$f"
done
```